# google map api v3 don't load on laravel with a grey box

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to display a map on my actual position on laravel but that doesn't work.
Javascript code seems to be good because when i paste it in an other project it's working.
It's strange to because when I paste the doc's code of the google maps api it's not working too. I have a grey box in the map div. 
This is my javascript file:

```
$(function() {
  var pos = {};
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    pos = position.coords;
    initialize (pos);
  });



function initialize (pos) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
  var mapOptions= {
  center: myLatlng,
  zoom: 15
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }
});
```

and here my view:
    @extends('layouts.main')

```
@section('contenu')
<div>
  Itinéraire vers <span class="gras" id="city">{{{$city}}}</span>.
</div>

<canvas id="map-canvas"></canvas>


{{ HTML::script('js/getRoute.js') }}
@stop
```

I call my jquery/map/script (in that order) in the layout. I can see in the developper map that i receive tile of the map of my location but my map stay grey.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, i my case i just set the center and map displayed properly. 
Here is my initialize function,.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463);
  map.setCenter(myLatlng);
  var viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
  document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = viewportheight + "px";
}
```

```css
 #map-canvas{
 width:100%;
 min-height:100px;
 }
```

```html
@extends('../master/head')
@section('main_content')
<div class="container" style="padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;max-width:none;overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
       <div id="map-canvas" ></div> 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
@stop
@section('footer_script')
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
@stop
```